# Why is this List<Double> isn't storing any data in the Room database?

Tags: android, arraylist, type-conversion, android-room

I'm using double values from a database to populate a chart. I use `List<String>` to add items in the same method and at the same time so there should be items in this list, too. Items in the `List<String>` are saved returned properly but `List<Double>` size is 0. Maybe the problem is in the type convertors?

Here's how I use type convertors to save to the Room database:
`Convertors.class`

```
@TypeConverter
    public String fromDoubleArray(List<Double> values) {
        String string = "";
        for(double d : values)
            string += (d + ",,,");

        return string;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public List<Double> toDoubleArray(String concatenatedStrings) {
        List<Double> doubleList = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] doubleStrings = concatenatedStrings.split(",,,");
        for (int i=0; i<doubleList.size(); i++) {
            doubleList.add(Double.parseDouble(doubleStrings[i]));
        }

        return doubleList;
    }
```

This is how I add list items:

```
List<Double> balanceHistory = selectedAccount.getBalanceHistory();
balanceHistory.add(newBalance);
selectedAccount.setBalanceHistory(balanceHistory);
accountsViewModel.update(selectedAccount);
```

Dao class:

```
@Dao
public interface AccountsDao {

    @Insert
    void insert(Account account);

    @Update
    void update(Account account);

    @Delete
    void delete(Account account);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM accounts_table")
    List<Account> getAllAccounts();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM accounts_table")
    LiveData<List<Account>> getAllAccountsLive();

}
```

Account class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "accounts_table")
public class Account implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private List<Double> balanceHistory;
    //codes...
    
    public Account(.....List<Double> balanceHistory....) {
        this.balanceHistory = balanceHistory;
        //....
    }

    public List<Double> getBalanceHistory() {
        return balanceHistory;
    }

    public void setBalanceHistory(List<Double> balanceHistory) {
        this.balanceHistory = balanceHistory;
    }

    //codes...
}
```

`AccountsDatabase`

```
@Database(entities = {Account.class}, version = 2, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(Converters.class)
public abstract class AccountsDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static AccountsDatabase instance;

    public abstract AccountsDao accountsDao();

    public static synchronized AccountsDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    AccountsDatabase.class, "accounts_database")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your DAO class

Comment: Where is an Account class and converters for it

Comment: @StanislavBatura just added them too